# Set TextMate to use Allman indentation for PHP

Tags: textmate, indentation

For programming PHP with TextMate (OS X) I'd like it to use Allman indentation:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    echo($i);
}
```

Rather than the default indentation:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    echo($i);
}
```

I can only find bundles to re-indent existing code, but not to simply use this indentation by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be simple. Simply press `enter` first, then type the first curly brace, like so:

1. Type `for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)`
2. Press `enter`
3. Type the opening curly brace `{`

Code will then be formatted like so:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    echo($i);
}
```